# how to track the user timings( start time and end time) for Silverlight application using google analytics...?

Tags: silverlight, google-analytics

I have recently signed-up at Google Analytics and also new to same.

I want to track the button click and user start time and end time using google analytics.

I have also received following javascript from Google analytics:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        (
function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
  m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-########-1', 'blahblah.com');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

I know how to call javascript function from .net application, but how to deal with user timings, I have also refered the link
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings

but didn't found helpful/fruitful.

Please help soon, your early response is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vijay.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Event Tracking with value. Start a timer when silverlight loaded or with a click button and you need to send the total time when you decide it's the end;

_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'User Actions', 'Session Duration', 'Tom Hanks', 49.9, true]);

you may either create custom reports for each user or default event reports for averages.